# converting a simple list to a dictionary (in python)

Tags: python

I'm learning python. I have a list of simple entries and I want to convert it in a dictionary where the first element of list is the key of the second element, the third is the key of the fourth, and so on. How can I do it?

```
list = ['first_key', 'first_value', 'second_key', 'second_value']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please never name anything list (or `str` or `dict`). It overwrites the builtin with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myDict = dict(zip(myList[::2], myList[1::2]))
```

Please do not use 'list' as a variable name, as it prevents you from accessing the list() function.

If there is much data involved, we can do it more efficiently using iterator functions:

```
from itertools import izip, islice
myList = ['first_key', 'first_value', 'second_key', 'second_value']
myDict = dict(izip(islice(myList,0,None,2), islice(myList,1,None,2)))
```

Answer (score 4):

The most concise way is

```
some_list = ['first_key', 'first_value', 'second_key', 'second_value']
d = dict(zip(*[iter(some_list)] * 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list is large, you end up wasting memory by building slices or eager zips. One way to convert the list more lazily is to (ab)use the list iterator and `izip`.

```
from itertools import izip

lst = ['first_key', 'first_value', 'second_key', 'second_value']
i = iter(lst)
d = dict(izip(i,i))
```

Answer (score 0):

The KISS way:

Use exception and iterators

```
    myDict = {}

    it = iter(list) 

    for x in list:
        try:
            myDict[it.next()] = it.next()
        except:
            pass



    myDict
```